# Is it possible to log what data was queried from an RDS database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I recently had a malfunctioning ORM that was generating bad queries and returning the wrong data for users. Is it possible to determine what data was being returned for individual queries?  I have RDS query / general logging enabled.

Comment: Most ORMs have a logging capability which allow you to see the raw query and what data is being returned. Which ORM are you using?

Comment: Which ORM are you using ? It's better to enable the logging for that ORM as it will help in understanding use-case by use-case.

Comment: GORM is the current ORM but I expect to change it after this experience